# How do I write a subdomain redirect?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, wp-redirect

I'm trying to write a redirect so that anyone who tries visiting "www.example.au" is directed to "www.example.com", but I'm not sure how to do that in my .htaccess file.

So far, I've tried:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^.au /
RedirectMatch 301 https://www.example.au /
RedirectMatch 301 ^.au /
```

But I'm not seeing any results. What's the proper way to setup this redirect?

Comment: Added an answer, and for reference note this isn't specifically a Wordpress question, even though it may be to do with a Wordpress site for you. You may find this quesiton gets closed or you get better results for non Wordpress questions on stack overflow or server fault

Comment: What you describe is not a "subdomain" redirect; it's an entirely different domain.

Answer (score 1):

Found answer [here](https://wpscholar.com/blog/redirect-old-domain-to-new-domain-via-htaccess/), first result by searching `redirect to different domain apache htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.au$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.au$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It doesn't matter if just your TLD is different the same format will work